# Unable to save 1:1 property: Either get "Cannot Insert when IDENTITY_INSERT is off" or "Dependent property is mapped to a store-generated column"

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am currently in the process of making a new application for a client who is currently using a 20-year old Access-based application to suit his needs. As part of this upgrade he wants me to still transfer over the legacy data records so that his users can still access the old data.

As part of the overhaul users may now define a Client's default settings for some generated reports (to be done later). This means that I have 2 objects with a 1:1 relationship between them: `Client` and `ClientSettings`, the latter having not been there before. I've gone on and successfully imported the old data into my new system and am now in the middle of testing out the screens and new features.

I keep running into a problem, though, with the `ClientSettings`. No matter what I do I seem to get an error whenever I try to save it. Here's what I currently have for `ClientSettings`:

```
public class ClientSettings
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Client")]
    public int SettingsID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public FinancialPeriods FinancialDataPeriodDefault { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public FinancialPeriods EmployeeDataPeriodDefault { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public FinancialPeriods MiscDataPeriodDefault { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool ExcludeFromComparisonIfNotSubjectAgency { get; set; }

    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

Part of the save function for the `ClientSettings` is as follows:

```
var settings = new ClientSettings {
  EmployeeDataPeriodDefault = (FinancialPeriods) View.EmployeeDataComboBox.SelectedIndex,
  FinancialDataPeriodDefault = (FinancialPeriods) View.FinancialDataComboBox.SelectedIndex,
  MiscDataPeriodDefault = (FinancialPeriods) View.MiscDataComboBox.SelectedIndex,
  ExcludeFromComparisonIfNotSubjectAgency = View.ExcludeFromComparisonCheckBox.Checked
 };

 if(SettingsRepository == null) SettingsRepository = new LinkTableRepository<ClientSettings>();

 if (CurrentClient.ClientSettings == null)
 {
   SettingsRepository.Add(settings);
   settings.SettingsID = CurrentClient.ID;
   SettingsRepository.Save();
 }
```

I either get one of two exceptions. Either I get (when `SettingsID` is set to `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`):

`A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column`

Or (without it) I get: `Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ClientSettings' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF`

How do I get around this problem and just save the records?

Thanks.

Comment: What approach do you use - database first or code first?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like EF tries to create identity column for primary key property by default.
Try to reset this explicitly:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.None)]
[Key, ForeignKey("Client")]
public int SettingsID { get; set; }
```

(probably, you'll have to drop database and create it again).

**Update.**

This code works for me:

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ClientSettings
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Client"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int SettingsId { get; set; }
    public bool SomeSetting { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}

class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClientSettings> ClientSettings { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
            // this is the case, when client and its settings are new entities
            var client = new Client { Name = "Jonh" };
            // note, that in this case you should initialize navigation property
            var clientSettings = new ClientSettings { Client = client, SomeSetting = true };

            context.ClientSettings.Add(clientSettings);
            context.SaveChanges();

            // this is the case, when client already exists in database, and settings are new entity
            var client2 = new Client { Name = "Mary" };
            context.Clients.Add(client2);
            context.SaveChanges();

            // in this case you can initialize either navigation property, or foreign key property
            var clientSettings2 = new ClientSettings { SettingsId = client2.Id, SomeSetting = true };
            context.ClientSettings.Add(clientSettings2);
            context.SaveChanges();
```

Also, I've checked the database - table for `ClientSettings` has non-identity primary key, which is correct.